# ITMS-90038: Malformed InfoPlist.strings file: '${filePath}' when publishing app using expo

Tags: react-native, app-store, expo

I'm using expo to build my react native app, and i need to add localization to my app, but whenever i upload my IPA using transporter, i get the following error "ITMS-90038: Malformed InfoPlist.strings file: '${filePath}'". Here's my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MYAPP",
    "slug": "MYAPP",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.my.MYAPP",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.3",
      "supportsTablet":true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true
      }
    },
    "locales": {
      "en": "./constants/en.json",
      "pt": "./constants/pt.json"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.my.MYAPP",
      "versionCode": 3,
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.myapp.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/OAuth"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "description": ""

  }
}
```

and here are my pt.json and en.json files:

```
{   //pt.json
    "CFBundleDisplayName": "MYAPP",
    "NSCameraUsageDescription": "\"MYAPP\" gostaria de aceder à sua câmera, para poder adicionar uma imagem ao seu perfil ou a uma ocorrência",
    "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "\"MYAPP\" gostaria de poder guardar imagens" ,
    "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "\"MYAPP\" gostaria de aceder às suas imagens, para poder adicionar uma imagem ao seu perfil ou a uma ocorrência"
}
```

```
{   //en.json
    "CFBundleDisplayName": "MYAPP",
    "NSCameraUsageDescription": "\"MYAPP\" would like to access your camera, in order to add an image to your profile or to an occurrence",
    "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "\"MYAPP\" would like to save images" ,
    "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "\"MYAPP\" would like to access your photos, in order to add an image to your profile or to an occurrence"
}
```

Is there any other type of setting up that i need to do? Or do i have any type of error in my code?

Comment: I too have this issue. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue come from the `\"`, expo use `app.json` to create `Info.plist`.

To see how expo create this file you can run `expo prebuild` to generate the native code of your project and check the result of `Info.plist`.

In en.json:

```
{
    ...
    "NSCameraUsageDescription": "\"MYAPP\" would like to access your camera, in order to add an image to your profile or to an occurrence",
    ...
}
```

Resulting in `./ios/MYAPP/Supporting/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`

```
...
NSCameraUsageDescription = ""MYAPP" would like to access your camera, in order to add an image to your profile or to an occurrence";
...
```